# What to write in expression in click='{expression}'?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have added marker to google map and now I want to show the location name when clicked on the marker. I have read the API documentation but i am not sure what to write in the expression of click and other properties.

help me with this expression part.
I am using all this in angularjs.

My code is

```
<marker coords='{"latitude":place.location.latitude, "longitude": place.location.longitude}'
            click='{expression}'
            ></marker>
```

Comment: Simply just `click='alert("your title")'` ??

Comment: its not working...i am still unable to click on the marker..

Answer (score 0):

Define some function in controller (or directive link function), like

```
$scope.print = function(location){
    console.log(location);
}
```

then just `ng-click="print(place.location)"`